# Laravel QueryBuilder condition

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, I want to build a query like following.

There is a `status column`, value should be `0` or `1`.

And there is another column, `device_ids` with `array`.

Now,in query, I want to apply different logic on `device_ids`, when status is `0` and status is `1`.

Can someone suggest me best possible way.

```php
$builder->where('status','0')->whereJsonDoesntContain('device_ids', $imei_id->id)

$builder->where('status','1')->whereJsonContains('device_ids', $imei_id->id)
```

How can I combine both ?

```
$all_applications = $builder->where('status', $model->status) 
->when($status, function ($query) { 
    Log::error("One"); 
    return $query->whereJsonContains('device_ids', 107); }, 
  function($query) { 
   Log::error("Zero"); return $query
  ->whereJsonDoesntContain('device_ids', 107); });
```

If I use $model->status , it gives me error like , "Undefined variable: model"

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly do you mean "apply different logic"? what information are you trying to get, and under what conditions?

Comment: $builder->orderBy('weight', 'desc')->where('progress','complete')->whereJsonDoesntContain('device_ids', $imei_id->id);

Comment: Here if the status = 1 , I want to apply , whereJsonContains

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

```php
$result = YourModel::where('status', $status)
    ->when($status, function ($query) {
        return $query->whereJsonContains('device_ids', $imei_id->id);
    }, function ($query) {
        return $query->whereJsonDoesntContain('device_ids', $imei_id->id);
    });
```

Comment: This looks great , but , I want both 0 and 1 status enteries.$result = YourModel::where('status', $status)
    ->when($status == 1, function ($query) {
        return $query->whereJsonContains('device_ids', $imei_id->id);
    }, function ($query) {
        return $query->whereJsonDoesntContain('device_ids', $imei_id->id);
    });

Comment: can we do something like this ?

Comment: It is currently doing so, read the attached documentation. The first function will be run if the value (`$status` in this case) is a truish value, in your case would be `1`, and the second function is run only if that value is falsy, `0` in your case.

Comment: But I dont want to pass the $status value manully , there is a column in table called , status. If the value of status is 1 then when function and of 0 then else statement should get called.

Comment: But that is no problem, use the model variable and access that part... You have to sbare the code you want to use. If you want to use a column, use a model like `$model->status`, that is basic PHP/Laravel.

Comment: $all_applications = $builder->where('status', $model->status)
                ->when($status, function ($query) {
                    Log::error("One");
                    return $query->whereJsonContains('device_ids', 107);
                }, function ($query) {
                    Log::error("Zero");
                    return $query->whereJsonDoesntContain('device_ids', 107);
                });

Comment: If I use $model->status , it gives me error like , "Undefined variable: model"

Comment: Update your question with the code not working, you are surely missing `use ($model)`

Comment: So, where does `$model` variable come from ?

Comment: this is what I am saying. I have a table called applications. Now in that table I have a column "status" and "device_ids". now status can have two values. 0 or 1. Now, when use calles the applications api, query should check for the status column. if status is 0 , then some logic should apply on device_ids column. And when status is 1, then different logic.